# Create custom labels for Custom object fields

Tags: custom-object, customlabel, translation

Is it possible to create a custom label for a field in a custom object in order to enable translation across languages?

Comment: Why don't you use Translation Workbench instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to translate only the field label in different language then follow.

**Setup--> Translate --> Select Language --> Select 'Custom Field' in setup component --> Select Custom Object --> Select 'Field label' in aspect**

You will be able to provide translation for the selected language.
Creating a custom label is not possible for this use case.

Comment: okay. So Translation Workbench is the only option. thanks